# Kotlin - Concatenate values of multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have a question about multi-dimensional arrays in Kotlin.
How do I achive following result in a generic way :

```
val array1 = arrayOf(
                arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4),
                arrayOf(5, 6, 7, 8),
                arrayOf(9, 10, 11, 12)
             )

val array2 = arrayOf(
                arrayOf(11, 12, 13, 14),
                arrayOf(15, 16, 17, 18),
                arrayOf(19, 20, 21, 22)
             )

val array3 = arrayOf(
                arrayOf(21, 22, 23, 24),
                arrayOf(25, 26, 27, 28),
                arrayOf(29, 30, 31, 32)
             )
```

Result by concatenating values (at column and row) of array1, array2, array3 in a array of same size :

```
result[0][0] = [array1[0][0], array2[0][0], array3[0][0]]
result[0][1] = [array1[0][1], array2[0][1], array3[0][1]]
result[2][0] = [array1[2][0], array2[2][0], array3[2][0]]
```

....

```
result = [
    [1, 11, 21], [2, 12, 22], [3, 13, 23], [4, 14, 24],
    [5, 15, 25], [6, 16, 26], [7, 17, 27], [8, 18, 28],
    [9, 19, 29], [10, 20, 30], [11, 21, 31], [12, 22, 32]
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps transpose the elements in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. Note that this assumes all arrays and subarrays are of the same size.

```
val array1 = arrayOf(
        arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4),
        arrayOf(5, 6, 7, 8),
        arrayOf(9, 10, 11, 12)
)

val array2 = arrayOf(
        arrayOf(11, 12, 13, 14),
        arrayOf(15, 16, 17, 18),
        arrayOf(19, 20, 21, 22)
)

val array3 = arrayOf(
        arrayOf(21, 22, 23, 24),
        arrayOf(25, 26, 27, 28),
        arrayOf(29, 30, 31, 32)
)
val arrays = arrayOf(array1, array2, array3)

val arrayLength = array1.size
val subArrayLength = array1[0].size 
val result = Array(arrayLength * subArrayLength) { index ->
    arrays.map{ it[index / subArrayLength][index % subArrayLength] }.toTypedArray()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatten()`

```
val result = arrayOf(array1, array2, array3).flatten().toTypedArray()
```

Since,`flatten` return a list, you can then call `toTypedArray()` to get result in form of array. This is more idiomatic way.